# How to implement notifications for expiring items?

Tags: java, spring, scheduling, backend, notifications

I am working on a Java / Spring web application. The application issues licenses on demand. Each license has an expiry date. Licenses can be renewed by the admin. I want to send an email notification or perform some operation 90, 45, 30, x, y, z no. of days before the license expiry. The email notification to be sent exactly before those number of days (not required to be accurate to minutes) is a contractual obligation and must be sent until the license is renewed.

I'm thinking of following ways to implement this.

- Implement a Spring Scheduler that runs once every day and checks for licensing expiring after current day + `x` days and send out an email notification. However, I'm concerned about the job not running on a specific day like application maintenance etc. For eg, 45th-day email can be missed as the job did not run on 45th day. Seems like error prone. To avoid that, Set a 90, 45, 30, x, y, z columns in another table against each license, but for the 2nd renewal, this will be a problem. To avoid that, keep track of the days the scheduler is run so if the scheduler does not run on any day or does not finish successfully, re-run it manually.

This is a stateless web app running multiple instances. Should I be implementing these sort of operations as a separate batch job or within the web application as a scheduler?

Will appreciate any ideas or pointers to resources.

Comment: If these notifications are critical to your business, better have'em running apart from the web. As Spring Batch into another war or as a system servíce. Maintenance over the web app should not affect (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented similar behaviour with RabbitMQ delayed messages.

The only thing you had to make sure was working was the message routing, because if a delayed message could not be routed at scheduled time it would be discarded (as per AMQP).

Other than that the implementation is really straightforward and simple, you set up a publisher and consumer pair just like you would when using regular RabbitMQ messages.

---

In your case you would:

1. take the expiration date of an item,
2. subtract the number of days when a notification shall be sent for that specific item,
3. convert the subtracted date from step 2 to timestamp,
4. subtract timestamp of current date from tinestamp from the step 3,
5. use timestamp from step 4 as a number of seconds for delay.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you take a look at the Quartz scheduler rather than waste time reinventing the wheel.  I've had great success with the .Net version of it.  http://www.quartz-scheduler.org is for the Java version.